# Fetch images with Callback in Picasso?

Tags: android, picasso

I want to show a photo series with no gaps in-between the photos, where photos change in a regular interval. I realized Picasso initializes the ImageView before it starts downloading, and it always does that, no matter if I fetch() or not before calling into().

I fetch() to keep the gap between images small and also use .placeholder(R.color.black), but the gap is still visible, even when the image is loaded from memory.

My code looks like this

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url).fetch();
```

then with a delay [which is currently fix and which I want to adjust dependent on network speed]

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url).into(screenSurface);
```

I noticed that fetch() does not support any callback parameters and returns void, so it seems it's not possible for me to know when the cache is warmed.

Two questions:

1. Can I get noticed when an image is cached?
2. Is there maybe a different way to get rid of the breaks between the images and make them appear regularly.

[I know I could manually code this somehow, but if Picasso supports it, I'd like to use it.]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on [the source](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/FetchAction.java), it looks like `fetch` does nothing upon completion, including notifying any potential listeners. Unfortunately, `FetchAction` isn't a public class, so you can't override this functionality either.

You can workaround this problem by using a custom `Target` subclass, like this:

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url).into(new Target() {
    @Override public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        // cache is now warmed up
    }
    @Override public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) { }
    @Override public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) { }
});
```

Comment: This is very nice, but I realized I cannot use functions like .fit() or .centerCrop() as I used them before, which is not a problem as I can set the appropriate attributes in the ImageView. But what I would like to know is if using Target() has any implications on caching images. Are the images cached as downloaded so I could technically use them in differently sized previews? Or will I need to .resize() manually or anything the like?

Comment: You can call `load(url).fit().into(screenSurface)` after using the workaround in my solution, and as long as `url` is the same, I believe it will be loaded from the cache.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an older question but the `fetch()` command allows for callbacks such as `fetch(Callback callback)`. 
This has an `onSuccess()` and `onError()` callback for the requested URI load.

See [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#fetch-com.squareup.picasso.Callback-) for javadoc details

Answer (score 0):

The `.into()` method provides a second argument which is a callback to success and failure. You can use this to keep track of when an image has arrived.

Javadoc: http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#into-android.widget.ImageView-com.squareup.picasso.Callback-

Have a look at this: [How to implement my own disk cache with picasso library - Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944773/how-to-implement-my-own-disk-cache-with-picasso-library-android)  Jake Wharton himself has an answer there.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the Callback in into() and I am using it, but  to get a smooth image sequence, I need the information if/when the image is loaded BEFORE into() is called. I will look into implementing my own disk cache, which may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2.7 of Picasso, it does support callback with the **`fetch()`** method.

```
Picasso.get()
                    .load(url)
                    .fetch(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            //Success
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError(Exception e) {
                            //Error
                        }});
```

Comment: Yep, but where's the `Bitmap`?

Comment: Exactly, what a bad API design, provide the Bitmap onSuccess for godsake

Answer (score 0):

I tried `noPlaceholder` method to resolve the problem. I have tried many methods, but eventually found that the question is to make the previous picture wait for next picture.