# Get Smiley and text into string from edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, emoji

In chat application i use emoji i am set it in edittext but while fetching it return an obj

```
EditText txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    try
    {
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(value);
        int size = txt.getHeight();
        d.setBounds(0, 0, size, size);  
        return d;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
    }
}; 

Spanned cs1 = Html.fromHtml("<img src='"+d+"'   />", imageGetter, null);
txt.getText().insert(txt.getSelectionStart(), cs1);
```

this is how i set emoji in edittext. now issue comes while fetching text+emoji

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setText(txt.getText().toString());
```

here i got text but not emoji it return obj

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194549/using-picasso-with-image-getter

Comment: How can i use it after creating PicassoImageGetter

Comment: help me bcz i am new in android

Comment: `String source`. You are not using `source`. What is `txt` ? Where is the EditText? `but while fetching`. Please show that code.